# Spring Boot Actuator with cors support and options request

Tags: cors, spring-boot-actuator, http-options-method

I have Spring Boot Actuator with cors support, which configurated in application.properties like this:

```
management.context-path=/management

endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
endpoints.cors.allowed-methods=GET,OPTIONS
endpoints.cors.allowed-headers=*
```

When i try to send request to this path with any headers I always get this error

```
 org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'OPTIONS' not supported
```

GET request works fine. What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration is ok, all works fine. The problem was in request path. When you send preflight request with AccessControlRequestMethod != GET to /managment/* (except /health) this exception occures. 
I think this is normal behavior, but it would be more understandable, if it throws 403, not 405